# Disable dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I tried like this

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Customer Type</label>
            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="customer_type" id="customer_type" onchange="get_corporate(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select Customer Type</option>
                <option value="1">Personal</option>
                <option value="2">Organization</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Company Name</label> <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="button" id="btn-addcompany">add</button> 
            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="company_name" id="company_name">
                <option>-- Select Company --</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($company as $value) {
                     echo"<option value='".$value['id']."'>".$value['name']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

but if company_name disable, variable company_name cannot undefined , how to solve?

Comment: i cannot share html on my question sorry

Comment: man that's answer area update your question.

Comment: i was updated..

Comment: what you whant do you want to disable the button and select box id anything other than 2 is selected.

Comment: if customer_type= personal, the user does not have to fill the company name

Comment: try the added answer.

Comment: company_name still undefined

Comment: yes it will be since only required property is disable but when you will access it in jquery it will give undefined. to solve this either set a default value for personal or don't read it. you can add value 0 to `<option ="0">-- Select Company --</option>` if not an issue. and check if type is not 1 the company value should be `> 0`.

Comment: see the update and try to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the button and select-box you can do this:you can disable the required property also.

```js
$(function(){
 $("#save").on("click",function(){
  var id = $('#customer_type').val();   
  if(id == ""){
       alert("Please select Customer Type");
      return;
  }
 var company=  $("#company_name").val();
 if(id != 1 && company == 0){
      alert("Please select your company");
     return;
 }  
 }); });  
function get_corporate(id){    
var id = $('#customer_type').val();    
   if (id == 2){
     $("#btn-addcompany").prop("disabled",false);
     $("#company_name").prop("required",true);
     $("#company_name").prop("disabled",false);
 }else{
  $("#btn-addcompany").prop("disabled",true);
     $("#company_name").prop("required",false);
     $("#company_name").prop("disabled",true);
 }   

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Customer Type</label>
            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="customer_type" id="customer_type" onchange="get_corporate()">
                <option value="">Select Customer Type</option>
                <option value="1">Personal</option>
                <option value="2">Organization</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Company Name</label> <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="button" id="btn-addcompany">add</button> 
            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="company_name" id="company_name">
                <option value="0">-- Select Company --</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
<button id="save" type="button">Save!</button>
```